# Angular 7 and IIS 7: Error Swapping to the Development environment

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis

I have in my Solution NET Core 2.2 an Angular 7 folder.
When i Run in Debug mode with Visual Studio 2017 and IIS Express, I can view web site and invoke correctly the backend's code API.
So, I Publish with Release choising my Profile setted in launchSettings.json , and copying content of "bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish" in the Folder in my Windows Server after i star IIS i have in page ,example http://localhost:8085/, the error below:

```
Development Mode Swapping to the Development environment displays detailed information about the error that occurred.

The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.
```

I set in web.config :

```
environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production"
```

How is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error says that there is a problem with our app, the underlying cause is not displayed on the error page. If you log your .NET core app errors in file, look there for detailed error, which should tell you exactly why our app failed.

Comment: I manage errors similar this page "Error Handling for MVC" https://wakeupandcode.com/handling-errors-in-asp-net-core/ , but in my file written in web.config thera aren't importanti info (handlerSetting name="debugFile") : <br/>[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Event Log: 'Application 'D:\myProject\Hello\' started the coreclr in-process successfully.' 
End Event Log Message. <br/>
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting app_offline monitoring in application 'D:\myProject\Hello\' <br/>
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting file watcher thread

Comment: Try adding event logger https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#built-in-logging-providers to capture error

Comment: you also can try starting the compiled site manually by running  generated exe, so that you can see what is going  on in console.

Comment: Thanks Alexandr ! I solve with command line dotnet , I see detail error in dos window "The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found" , then i change : spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp" in Startup, and "outputPath": "dist" in file Angular.json :-) thanks again

Comment: No problems, Glad to help, do not forget to mark question as answered

Comment: I Try operation and appear "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." thanks